# "I wouldn't really recommend it" in British vs American English

Tags: meaning, transatlantic-differences

Consider this phrase and context:

> "One could do X. One could also do Y, *but I wouldn't really recommend*
> *it*."

(The general "you" instead of "one" could also be used, but I use "one" here for clarity)

There are two interpretations under consideration:

1. As a native speaker of American English, I'd previously believed that **without additional context**, the default meaning for most speakers of both dialects is that the speaker doesn't recommend X *for anyone*.
2. A colleague suggests that this formulation is sufficient context in British English to indicate that the speaker doesn't recommend X *for that specific listener* - for example, because of limitations in that listener's capabilities that would make X dangerous for them, but OK for experienced people.

To convey interpretation #2, I would expect that a speaker in either would have to provide a little more context - for example, to explicitly say:

> "One could do X. One could also do Y, but I wouldn't really recommend that
> *you* do it."

Is interpretation #2 common in British English?

Comment: Pragmatics is always defining. The scope intended with "I wouldn't really recommend it" is dependent on prior dialogue, the situation obtaining (including the depth of the relation between A and B), and speaker A's command of English (a factor that's impossible to evaluate here). The prior dialogue here being general, the balance is tipped strongly in favour of the generalised warning, though if the matter is very important the scope ambiguity should be resolved.

Comment: With no other context available I would take it to mean that Y is more the one to be avoided. I happen to be British, but I cannot honestly think that interpretation here would depend in any way on what variety of English one spoke.

Comment: As WS2. The thing you don't recommend is in the same sentence, not an earlier one. However "One *could* do X. But one could also do Y, so I wouldn't really recommend it" refers to X.

Comment: Stereotypically, if a Brit *wouldn't really recommend* something, he means ***you shouldn't touch it with a barge pole**.* Where an American saying exactly the same thing might simply mean something along the lines of  ***It's not ideal*** (which to a Brit means it's the absolute pits! :)

Comment: Americans are also quite capable of irony, sarcasm, and understatement. I'd say it would be hard to make a generalization about how the interpretations of your examples would differ depending on which type of English is being spoken. I don't think there's much difference.

Comment: Firstly your statements are recommending not to do Y. Secondly, you said *'The general "you" instead of "one" could also be used, but I use "one" here for clarity'* - when phrased with "one" the recommendation applies to everybody; I definitely wouldn't take it as a recommendation applicable only to the person you're talking to. If you rephrased it with "you could" instead of "one could" *then* it could be specific to the person you're talking to.

Comment: I don’t know of any American (except now you) that would assume meaning #1.

Answer (score 0):

English, in all its forms, is a tonal language, and clues and context are also taken from visual expressions.

As general guidance, if we take “*Y’*”, as the unemphasised general “you”, and "***You***” as the emphasised specific/personal “you”, then we have:

1. "*Y’* could do X. *Y’* could also do Y, but I wouldn't really recommend it." - (General advice recommending X)
2. "*Y’* could do X. ***You*** could also do Y, but I wouldn't really recommend it." - (General advice followed by specific advice speaking against using the special skill at Y)
3. "***You***  could do X. *Y’* could also do Y, but I wouldn't really recommend it." (Almost a suggestion that "You" do X and dismissing Y.)
4. "***You*** could do X. ***You*** could also do Y, but I wouldn't really recommend it."

I suspect that it would also make a difference if the speaker thought that the listener were going to do the job  or have it done by someone else.

The upshot of this is that the construction is heavily dependent on more than a form or words.

Comment: Tone definitely matters, but English isn't a "tonal language" in the normal sense of that term, which is used for languages such as Mandarin where each syllable has an inherent pitch contour such that changing the tone can result in a completely unrelated word.

Answer (score 0):

The two interpretations of the phrase 'I wouldn't recommend it' that are outlined in the question, upon analysis, turn out not to be as different as the question assumes. That is equally true in British and in American English.

Suppose, for a moment, that (1) is the correct interpretation. What does it mean that the speaker wouldn't recommend it to anyone? Chances are that, upon analysis, it will almost always turn that the recommendation depends on some assumptions, understood from the context, about the circumstances that the person spoken to is in. If all these assumptions were to be made explicit, we would see that 'I wouldn't recommend it to anyone' really amounts to 'I wouldn't recommend it to anyone in circumstances A, B, C'. Of course, in real-life communication, the circumstances are not all explicitly listed, which means that there will sometimes be room for interpretation as to what precisely the (non)recommendation is. What is listed in the question as interpretation (1) is thus not a single, precise interpretation; it is something that is subject to further interpretation.

Now it may sometimes be that the circumstances that the speaker had in mind were the precise circumstances of the person receiving the advice, which very few other people are in. If that is the case, then (1) is not really different from (2).

What this shows is that (2) is a special case of (1). When we hear 'I wouldn't recommend it', the question should not be whether to interpret it as (1) or (2), but what are the circumstances on which the (non)recommendation is based.